# VSC trigger path intellisense without dashes

Tags: visual-studio-code

Path intellisense in VSC is triggered by using dashes, e.g. './ triggers intellisense, just ./ doesn't. However, for e.g. latex it would be nice to trigger intellisense without the dashes. Is it possible to configure this?